# SVN and Initial commit of an Ionic Project?

Tags: svn, ionic-framework, version-control, terminal

I'm using SVN, and I have an Ionic project with it's **initial** commit (I haven't committed any file before) where I need several directories (/node_modules, /plugins etc) I don't need under source control.

How can I ignore the content of several directory/folder with SVN in initial commit ?

I am using OS X and commandline.

Answer (score 2):

There is the **--depth** option doing exactly what you need:

```
svn add <foldername1> <foldername2> --depth empty
```

you can use instead of "empty" also the following, self explaining values:

- immediates
- files
- infinity